# How to Uninstall Ruby Version?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

How is one **supposed** to remove rubies from rbenv? From the rbenv ["How it Works"](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#section_1) it seems that one can simply delete the ruby version from the *versions* directory and then execute `rbenv rehash`. Anyone know definitely?

Comment: (And what else could you do?)

Comment: I think I missed the point. You're asking how to delete rubies from rbenv and then provide the answer in the question?

Comment: @withadot: I provided the approach I tried, which did not work; hence the question. I should have included the fact it didn't work for me in my OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uninstall ruby version from rbenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147457/uninstall-ruby-version-from-rbenv)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's all it takes. You'll probably want to make sure your default Ruby version is set to a version that you're *not* deleting, too.