# uninstall ruby version from rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

How to uninstall or remove ruby version from [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). I have installed two versions of ruby. While switching to ruby 1.9.3, I am getting segmentation fault. Can anyone please help, how to remove a particular version from rbenv?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

**New way**

Use the `uninstall` command: `rbenv uninstall [-f|--force] <version>`

```
rbenv uninstall 2.1.0  # Uninstall Ruby 2.1.0
```

Use `rbenv versions` to see which versions you have installed.

---

**Old way**

To remove a Ruby version from rbenv, delete the corresponding directory in `~/.rbenv/versions`. E.g.

```
rm -rf ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0
```

Run `rbenv rehash` afterwards to clean up any stale shimmed binaries from the removed version.

Comment: I did that. But rbenv keeps telling me that the deleted version is missing.

Comment: @Mosselman You can delete the entry from `~/.rbenv/version` and the error will be avoided.

Comment: @Kashyap I have 'fixed' the issue by reinstalling, but I think it didn't have that particular entry that was popping up for me, but the error remained.

Comment: the directory is empty for me but I followed the advice from @Iorcon and that worked. "rbenv uninstall <version>"

Comment: will this remove all the gems of that version?

Answer (score 28):

ruby-build now adds an [uninstall command](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#uninstalling-ruby-versions) to rbenv to handle the removal of ruby versions, if you want to avoid manual `rm -fr` (which might be considered risky) and `rbenv rehash` suggested by @Stephenson. For removing ruby version 1.9.3-p0 you would run the following:

```
rbenv uninstall 1.9.3-p0
```

Comment: It would be awesome if this could become the accepted answer, as it's definitely the right way to go.

Comment: Does this remove gems?

Comment: @DanyalAytekin never too late to say Yes, it removes, afaik

Answer (score 4):

Like Stephenson said, but remember to change version & global if they are referencing the deleted version.

Comment: I keep getting a version error even after setting the global and local rbenv versions to a newer one.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command is well explained in other answers, However if you are trying to uninstall jruby then you need to explicitly mention `jruby` in command followed by hyphen and then gem version, For example:

`rbenv uninstall jruby-9.2.16.0`